# Regex for removing an item from a comma-separated string?

Tags: regex

Say I have a string like this: "1,2,3,11"

A simple regex like this will find a number in the string: `(?<=^|,)1(?=,|$)` - this will correctly find the "1" (ie. not the first "1" in "11").

However, to *remove* a number from the string, leaving the string properly formatted with commas in between each number, I need to include *one adjacent comma only*. For example, matching `1,`, `2,` or `,11`.

So the trick is to match *one* comma, on *either* side of the number, but to *ignore* the comma on the opposite side (if there is one). Can someone help me with this?

Ed: Should mention this has to be done in code, not using external tools.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/pN2fD6 ?

Comment: So you want to match preceding comma and number, but leave the comma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> to remove a number from the string, leaving the string properly
> formatted with commas in between each number

Try using following `regex` and replace with empty string.

```
\b1\b,?|,\b1\b$
```

this regex has two alternatives (`|`)

- `\b1\b,?`, this one will basically matches `1,` or `1` (using suggestion from [Goozak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854760/goozak))
- `,\b1\b$`, this one will basically matches `,1` **at the end of the line** (`$`)

In both case the word boundary `\b` is positioned around `1`, but in reality it's useful only if one want to capture the beginning or the end of a word.

> A word boundary is a position that is either preceded by a word character and not followed by one or followed by a word character and not preceded by one.

For example it can be useful to replace the first char or last char of a word.

In this very example if the goal is to remove an item in the comma separated list, this is not really useful.

---

Using `sed`

```bash
sed -e 's/\b1\b/,/g' -e 's/,,//g'
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm doing this in a programming language, so can't use a commandline tool.

Comment: @ingredient_15939 you can do same 2 level of parsing in any programming language that support search and replace. Which language bdw?

Comment: Thanks for the update - tried it out in regex buddy and it seems to work a treat - even if the number is repeated in the list, which is perfect. I didn't think of that approach; simple and elegant.

Comment: Additionally, you could make the first comma optionnal, to match the searched value even if it's alone: `\b1\b,?|,\b1\b$` would also match `1` if it was alone.

Answer (score 0):

for 3 (for example), you can use (with replace):

```
 /\b3\b,?/
```