# using a replace in coldfusion leaving trailing comma

Tags: coldfusion

I have a code where the values are coming as:

`a,b,c` from database..

now i want to remove `c` from the string based upon condition, `c` can be at any place, **1st**, **last** or **middle**.

i am using replace to do it like this:

```
<cfset answer = Replace('a,b,c','c','','all')>
```

This works but it leaves a trailing comma at the end or at the start or 2 commas in middle breaking the whole string, what can be my approach here

Comment: Rather than a replace, try using the ListDeleteAt() function. http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_13.html

Comment: but it throws error if that element is not there

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you actually storing csv lists ie "a,b,c" in a single column? If so, you should normalize your db tables. Storing comma delimited lists is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: nothing specific old code, it is stored like this in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfscript>
input = 'a,b,c';

foundAt = listFind(input, 'c');
answer = foundAt ? listDeleteAt(input, foundAt) : input;

writeOutput(answer);
</cfscript>
```

[Run this code LIVE on TryCF.com](http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=xgJz0SaV)

See: [List functions](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/List+functions)

OR use `REReplace()`.  The solution was just one google search away: [Regex for removing an item from a comma-separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827136/regex-for-removing-an-item-from-a-comma-separated-string)

```
function listRemoveAll(list, item) {
    return REReplace(list, "\b#item#\b,|,\b#item#\b$", "", "all");
}
```

Comment: it returns me 0 because u defined 0 at top, did not work as expected

Comment: Henry - I fixed a small error. The example now runs, even if the element is not found. Hope you do not mind.

Comment: rather than using the way told me, its awesome but what about a regex with single line, @henry- nothing offensive but i will love a way to do it in single line

Comment: @bingo see my updated answer for your one-liner regex solution.