# Regex: Find item in a delimited list

Tags: regex

I have mainly a `;` (semicolon) separated list and would like to extract those entries containing `lib1` from the list. In this case it would be `..\..\..\libs\lib1\include`

```
<A>..\src;..\include;..\..\..\libs\lib1\include;..\..\..\libs\lib2\include</A>
```

I tried with this regular expression

```
[>;](.*?lib1.*?[;<])
```

But it matches almost the whole thing

```
..\src;..\include;..\..\..\libs\lib1\include;
```

I suspect that I need some kind of lookahead, that I do not match another `;` character before the `lib1` occurs, but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Do a little searching, this has been answered many times.

Comment: I already did a fair amount of googling, there are examples on how to split between a list like this, [to remove an item in a list] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827136/regex-for-removing-an-item-from-a-comma-separated-string), but in this example the whole string to be removed is known. I only know part of the string to be matched. I also tried this expression with negative lookahead `[>;]((?!.*?;).*?lib1.*?[;<])`, but then it doesn't match anything any more.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using?  What language or editor are you doing this in?  Not all regex engines are created equal I'm afraid. Please add additional tags to your original post to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works when there is only one `lib1` in the list.  However you said `"entries"` (plural) so the catch is looping through each element which would be easier if we knew what language you are doing this in.  See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iG7vH1/2) for the example.

Here is the regex:

```
^.*[>;](.*lib1.*?)[;<]
```

Which can be read as:

```
^     Anchor to the beginning of the line
.*    Followed by zero or more of any characters
[>;]  Followed by a character class consisting of a greater-than sign or
       a semi-colon
(.*lib1.*?)  Followed by a remembered group of zero or more characters
              followed by the desired "lib1" followed by optional zero
              or more characters
[;<]  Followed by a character class consisting of a semi-colon 
       or a less-than sign
```