# Delete certain value of a field of separate database by commas and reenter again

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to delete a value from a separate database field by commas and re-enter again.

With the str_replace PHP function can delete all but the first or last, as always left a comma. I'm testing the end PHP function, more thank any solution.

```
$referenciaDel; // 44 

$referencia; // 44,45,46

$replace = str_replace(",".$referenciaDel,"",$referencia);
```

If the first value to be deleted does not work because it added the comma in the function and the first value has no comma before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827136/regex-for-removing-an-item-from-a-comma-separated-string

Comment: Do you want to do it in SQL or PHP ???

Comment: Like in PHP. I use mysqli

Comment: Do you want to delete it directly in the database? That perhaps makes more sense than fetching into php, deleting, updating database...!?

Comment: Yes I need to update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand you right.

```
$strFromDatabase = '1,2,3,4,5';

$toDelete = 4;
echo trim(str_replace([$toDelete, ',,'], ['', ','], $strFromDatabase), ',');
// output: '1,2,3,5'

$toDelete = 5;
echo trim(str_replace([$toDelete, ',,'], ['', ','], $strFromDatabase), ',');
// output: '1,2,3,4'

$toDelete = 1;
echo trim(str_replace([$toDelete, ',,'], ['', ','], $strFromDatabase), ',');
// output: '2,3,4,5'
```

Comment: Thanks @kaito in one line, perfect!